# wenzhixin bootstrap table no populating

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have this bootstrap table where I cannot populate with my data, on data-url im calling a function inside my controler, when I inspect the the object i can see that it loaded correctly but for some reason it not populating the table Am I missing somenthing?

```
<table id="t_user" class="table table-hover tbl_usr" 
   data-toggle="table"
   data-url="<?php echo site_url('mda_user/tblrefresh')?>"
   data-toolbar="#custom-toolbar"
   data-click-to-select="true"
   data-single-select="true"
   data-search="false"
   data-show-refresh="false"
   data-show-toggle="true"
   data-show-columns="true"
   data-pagination="true"
   data-search="true"
   data-height="300"
   data-response-handler="responseHandler">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true"><?= $id?> </th>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true"><?= $name?> </th>
        <th data-field="password"> <?=$password?></th>
        <th data-field="operate" 
            data-halign="center" 
            data-align="center"
            data-formatter="operateFormatter" 
            data-events="operateEvents">
            <?=$operation?>
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of your `responseHandler(res)` function?

eg, I defined my table mostly inline but also with some JS:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').bootstrapTable({
        url :  "/api/data",
        responseHandler: function(res) {
            return res.data.content;
        }
    })
```

(The response is wrapped in some JSON that I need to remove to pass the pure array to bootstrap-table)

Comment: Let me ask u this on your url on the response r u refering to a file called data ? in my case in my url at the table IM calling a controller and the a method inside. And I dont have a response function. I probably missed that on the docmentation.

Comment: My server responds with data wrapped in some extra JSON - I remove that wrapper in the responseHandler function I have defined as above.